# Is there a short way to assign all the anchors of a view equals to another view's all anchors

Tags: swift, autolayout, uikit

let's say I have a container view, which has an imageView and blurEffectView as its subView. In short, I apply a blurEffect on this image inside the container view.

I used anchors to configure the auto-layout programmatically without IB. And the anchors of `imageView` and `blurredEffectView` are completely the same as their container view.

I'm wondering is there a simple/quick way to do things like `aView.allAnchors.equals(bView's allAnchors)`? Then we could save a lot of repeating code.

```
- container
  - imageView
  - blurEffectView
```

```
    let container: UIView = {
        let aView = UIView()
        aView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return aView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        configureLayout()
    }
    
    func configureLayout() {
        
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Wang Fei"))
//        imageView.frame = container.bounds
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        container.addSubview(imageView)

        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
        let blurredEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurredEffectView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
//        blurredEffectView.frame = imageView.bounds
        container.addSubview(blurredEffectView)
        
        view.addSubview(container)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            container.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            container.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            container.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            container.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.42),
            
            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor),
            imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor),
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.topAnchor),
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.bottomAnchor),
            
            blurredEffectView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor),
            blurredEffectView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor),
            blurredEffectView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.topAnchor),
            blurredEffectView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
```

Comment: You can use frame instead of constraint.

Comment: Thanks, could you show me a small snippet on how to achieve it with frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a frame instead of a constraint. Also, in code setting constraint and view inside the `viewDidLayoutSubviews`it's not a good way. Also, use lazy.

Here is the possible solution.

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {
    private lazy var container: UIView = {
        let aView = UIView()
        aView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return aView
    }()

    
    private lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Red"))
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        return imageView
    }()
    
    private lazy var blurredEffectView: UIVisualEffectView = {
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
        let blurredEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurredEffectView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return blurredEffectView
    }()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        setViews()
    }

    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        self.imageView.frame = container.bounds
        self.blurredEffectView.frame = container.bounds
    }
    
    private func setViews() {
        view.addSubview(container)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            container.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            container.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            container.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            container.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.42)])
        
        container.addSubview(imageView)
        container.addSubview(blurredEffectView)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this `frame` example. And I try a little experiment on my side. More than this I use `let aView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.42))` in container closure, to completely remove `anchor` stuff in code. Don't know if it is the better way though the code is more neat now.

Comment: And yeah, the layout code should be in `viewDidLoad`, only bounds change would be put inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. But I don't agree with the lazy things, use `lazy` or not on those UI elements, they will be called only once, before `viewDidLoad` or after. So it is pointless to use lazy here.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in shortcut. So most people write one. Or they adopt an existing framework that provides such shortcuts; [SnapKit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit) is a popular choice.

Comment: So there is no native way to do this. However, good to know there is a dependency for auto-layout. I'd like to look its code, and maybe I could brings out some handy extension with myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the repeating code in a convenient `extension` like this -

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    func setUpEdgeToEdge(in container: UIView, insets: UIEdgeInsets = .zero) {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.topAnchor, constant: insets.top),
            self.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor, constant: insets.left),
            self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.bottomAnchor, constant: insets.bottom),
            self.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor, constant: -insets.right),
        ])
    }
}
```

Now you can call it like -

```
imageView.setUpEdgeToEdge(in: container)

// OR

imageView.setUpEdgeToEdge(in: container, insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 16, bottom: 10, right: 16))
```

Comment: This is i am also feeling good approach with dynamic padding support.